# What is the behavior of MMU in case a page fault is not handled?

Tags: linux-kernel, mmu

I was going through the do_page_fault (x86 arch) routine. Suppose a process tries to write to a shared page which is swapped out. Then as per the execution flow in do_page_fault, if the access is valid and it is  a normal page (not huge page) and the execution lets say came till do_swap_page (i.e., no errors). Once do_swap_page is executed, it returns.

1) But will there be a fault again in case swap-in itself was not handled due to some reason?

2) In general, I would like to know more detail about MMU like - does it check pte flags or vm area flags to raise fault on an address? Can anyone point me to the sources where I can understand how MMU does the checks for a memory access.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) But will there be a fault again in case swap-in itself was not handled due to some reason?

Yes. Fault will be generated again and again (ISR completes successfully), till page is in place. MMU doesn't track whether previous access to this page generated interrupt or not.

However, if page fault is triggered when previous fault is handled, [double fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_fault) will be triggered.

> 2) In general, I would like to know more detail about MMU like - does it check pte flags or vm area flags to raise fault on an address? Can anyone point me to the sources where I can understand how MMU does the checks for a memory access.

Yes, it checks.

You may check [OSDev](http://wiki.osdev.org/Paging) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate on your answer explaining "page faulting again and again till in place" and "double fault", because when a fault occurs again, is it not a double fault? I did not understand the difference between your 1st and second points.

Comment: "again and again" means that page fault was handled and then happens again. But if page fault is in process of handling (in ISR), double fault occurs.